# Dice Class attributes overlap when calling class function for different objects (Python)

Tags: python

When I create three instances of this dice class and call the roll function, I expect to get three separate lists of rolls with 2 rolls in each, that is, one unique list per instance `x, y` and `z`. Instead, every time I roll for a new dice I get the results from the other instances plus the new rolls... What am I doing wrong?

```
from random import randint 

class Dice:
    
    def __init__(self, results = [], nsides = 6):
        self.results = results
        self.nsides = nsides
        
    def roll(self, n):
        for i in range(n):
            self.results.append(randint(1, self.nsides))
        return(self.results)
        
x = Dice()
x.roll(2)
print(x.results)

y = Dice()
y.roll(2)
print(y.results)

z = Dice()
z.roll(2)
print(z.results)
```

Output:

```
[4, 6]
[4, 6, 5, 1]
[4, 6, 5, 1, 4, 3]
```

Expected:

```
[4, 6]
[5, 1]
[4, 3]
```

Note that the current output is the correct expected output if I would have ran `x.roll(2)` three times.

Comment: You could simply just ```self.results.clear()``` after ```self.results=results```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you use a mutable object as defaut parameter value, `results=[]`, the same list is used for each instance, change to

```
def __init__(self, results=None, nsides=6):
    self.results = results or []
    self.nsides = nsides
```